# adding wp store locator to woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding drop ship locations to woocommerce checkout. I was able to add wp store locator plugin to the checkout page. I don't know how to make the selected store details to populate the shipping address in checkout page. I am new to editing wordpress using php. Please explain in detail

Comment: Please update the question with the current code, what you have tried, research done etc. Go through the StackOverflow new user guide to understand how to ask questions which includes sufficient detail for the community to help you here.

Comment: Thank You for replying @unrealsoul007 . I dont have any codes on this issue . i was trying to use wp store locator plugin to send the selected store data to populate the shipping address. I was not able to think of any codes in php to do it . the following comment from junky suggestion gives a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Local Pickup Plus](https://woocommerce.com/products/local-pickup-plus/) plugin. With this plugin, the user can select a store location from the Cart / Checkout page. You can then adjust the verbiage on these pages to replace Pickup with Drop Shipping. Not the perfect solution and might not work in your situation but as a non-coder it may be worth a try.

Comment: Thank You, @Junky. This is exactly what i was looking for .[Local Pickup Pus]: (https://woocommerce.com/products/local-pickup-plus/) solves the issue. In addition to thisit would be really helpful if the customers can see the dropship locations in a map during checkout. I also want the customers to have a option to choose the location through maps as well.